# Relative Proj and generation of sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $π\colon Y = \mathrm{Proj}_B \mathcal{A} \rightarrow B$ be a morphism constructed from a coherent graded sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_B$-algebras $\mathcal{A} = \bigoplus_k \mathcal{A}$.

I am looking for (minimal) hypotheses for the natural morphism
$$
\mathcal{A_k} \rightarrow \mathcal π_*O_Y(k)
$$ 
to be surjective for $k\gg 0$. Is this perhaps always the case? Please excuse me if this follows directly from the definitions.

Stacks (Ex. 21.2) contains an example of a projectivisation of a coherent sheaf where injectivity at degree $k=1$ fails. That is all I could find.

Comment: Exercise 15.4.D in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic geometry http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjan2915public.pdf shows the surjectivity for large k if B is the spectrum of a field and A is a finitely generated graded ring over k. Exercise 17.2.F shows that you can reach surjectivity for a general relative Proj locally on B.

Comment: Your question is hardly understandable to me. What is $Y$ ? Your morphism seems independent from $k$ so what means the condition on $k$ ? What means $\Gamma_*$ ? What is the reference Stacks (Ex. 21.2) ?

Comment: I've removed ambiguities, thank you for pointing them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the base is affine Noetherian, this is discussed in [this section of the Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01YR). See especially the last two lemmas with graded module $M = A$. Also, I want to mention that I do not know what you mean by a "coherent sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_B$-algebras".

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. I was trying to find this from an old Stacks PDF and not the up-to-date website!